# How to draw best fit non linear curve in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

after lots of timing searching on net I come back to Stack overflow.can anyone tell me where i will get code for drawing best fit nonlinear curves in c# or wpf & combine curves of linear curve & non linear curves.Thank you

Comment: Please, care to name and tag your questions correctly if you wish to have them noticed and answered!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BezierSegment](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/WPFBezierCurves11072008024057AM/WPFBezierCurves.aspx).

[Plus some MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can fit an nth-order polynomial through n+1 points, using [Polynomial Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Programming it involves a little matrix arithmetic, since you end up [solving a system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) which you'd need to understand if you were going to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [Radial Basis Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) which fit curves very well. Whatever you do, you will need to use matrix algebra to solve a system of linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are asking for a programming answer to a mathematical question.

You need to elaborate on "best fit." That could mean a lot of different things depending on context. Do you have an underlying statistical model?  Do you need a "tracking algorithm" that updates after each new point with minimum computation? Are you removing seasonality or some other regular perturbation?

The answer could be as varied as Fast Fourier Series and exponential smoothing.